# How to resize a scrollable frame to fill the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

The frame that i want to be scrollable is on the left side. I want to expand it to "fill both".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#d3d3d3")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.pop()

    def pop(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.f = Label(self.frame, text=i,background="#ffffff", anchor="center")
            self.f.pack(side="top", fill="both")

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x500")
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When i pack said frame using self.frame.pack(), it centers and expands, but it becomes un-scrollable.

How do i properly pack this frame and use it for scrolling. Thanks.

Comment: You don't. Using `self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame)` is the equivalent of `self.frame.pack()` when placing things in a Canvas.

Comment: @Novel Alright. So how to get my desired effect. Which is expanding that frame to fill the canvas?

Comment: A canvas has no boundary. It's infinite in all directions. You can't fill it.

Comment: @Novel: while what you said is somewhat true, I think what is being asked is how to get the frame to expand to the visible portion of the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes. That is what i am asking. Basically the labels I'm putting inside "self.frame" are lining up to the left. I want them to be centered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to bind the `<Configure>` event of the canvas to a function that resizes the frame to fit the canvas.

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
        ...

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        # width is tweaked to account for window borders
        width = event.width - 4
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("self.frame", width=width)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I have read a lot of your responses on stackoverflow. You are a big help.