# Scrollable frame does not fill canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I use Python 2.7 and I have a scrollable frame where the canvas is not shrinking to fit the frame I want to make scrollable.

I looked at this question for an answer but it does not work when I run it:
[How to resize a scrollable frame to fill the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766670/how-to-resize-a-scrollable-frame-to-fill-the-canvas?rq=1)

When I print the width of the frame inside the canvas, it says 0.

I also ran the code from the answer of this question on my computer :
[Scrollable Frame does not resize properly using tkinter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063868/scrollable-frame-does-not-resize-properly-using-tkinter-in-python)
but it will still show the white canvas to the left of the labels, and it does not resize when the labels are deleted.

It looks like this:

[image: Canvas not resizing to fit scrollable frame]

This is my code, based on the answer in this question:
[Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

```
from Tkinter import *

class Scrollable_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, values):

        self.parent = parent

        Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.innerFrame = Radiobutton_frame(self.canvas,title,values)

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= N+S)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = N+S)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window = self.innerFrame,anchor="nw")

        self.innerFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.set_canvas_scrollregion)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def set_canvas_scrollregion(self, event):

        width = event.width - 4
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("self.innerFrame ", width=width)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


class Radiobutton_frame(LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, values):

        """            
        In: parent - Canvas
            title - String
            values - List of Int
        """

        self.radiobuttons = {}
        self.parent = parent

        self.selection = StringVar()
        self.selection.set("init")

        LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text = title)

        for value in values:
            self.add_radiobutton(value)


    def add_radiobutton(self, value):

        """
        Adds a radiobutton to the frame.

        In: item - String
        """

        # Associate to same variable to make them function as a group
        self.radiobuttons[value] = Radiobutton(master = self,
                                                variable = self.selection,
                                                text = value,
                                                value = value)
        self.radiobuttons[value].pack(anchor=W)

# Usage example

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
scrollableFrame = Scrollable_frame(root, "Canvas not resizing", range(30))
scrollableFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you'd want as well?

Comment: You say that you tried the suggestion to bind on the `<Configure>` event of the canvas and it didn't work. That's the solution, so can you show what  you tried and explain what "didn't work" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think above question's code snippet fits to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but at the very least it's runnable.

---

You have three mistakes compared to that of: [How to resize a scrollable frame to fill the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766670/how-to-resize-a-scrollable-frame-to-fill-the-canvas?rq=1)

The most significant of which is that in the linked question, the OP uses the option `tags` where you don't. Replace:

```
self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window = self.innerFrame,anchor="nw")
```

with:

```
self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window = self.innerFrame, anchor="nw", tags="my_tag")
```

Another mistake is that you're binding the event of a frame's resizing as opposed to the actual Canvas' resizing, also pointed out in [Bryan's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598382/scrollable-frame-does-not-fill-canvas#comment84193660_48598382). Replace:

```
self.innerFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.set_canvas_scrollregion)
```

with:

```
self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.set_canvas_scrollregion)
```

Lastly, tkinter doesn't seem to accept space character with tags, replace:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure("self.innerFrame ", width=width)
```

with:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure("my_tag", width=width)
```

Finally, you should have:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Scrollable_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, values):

        self.parent = parent

        Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.innerFrame = Radiobutton_frame(self.canvas,title,values)

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= N+S)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = N+S)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window = self.innerFrame,anchor="nw",
                                                                tags="my_tag")

        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.set_canvas_scrollregion)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def set_canvas_scrollregion(self, event):

        width = event.width - 4
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("my_tag", width=width)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


class Radiobutton_frame(LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, values):

        """            
        In: parent - Canvas
            title - String
            values - List of Int
        """

        self.radiobuttons = {}
        self.parent = parent

        self.selection = StringVar()
        self.selection.set("init")

        LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text = title)

        for value in values:
            self.add_radiobutton(value)


    def add_radiobutton(self, value):

        """
        Adds a radiobutton to the frame.

        In: item - String
        """

        # Associate to same variable to make them function as a group
        self.radiobuttons[value] = Radiobutton(master = self,
                                                variable = self.selection,
                                                text = value,
                                                value = value)
        self.radiobuttons[value].pack(anchor=W)

# Usage example

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
scrollableFrame = Scrollable_frame(root, "Canvas not resizing", range(30))
scrollableFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate your time and effort for helping me out. Actually I wanted the canvas to shrink to the inner frame size and not the inner frame to expand to fill the canvas. Its not a problem since I can hardcode the size of the canvas to be approximately the size of the inner frame. It surprised me that a print statement tells me the inner frame is 0 after it has been painted on the canvas, maybe somebody knows why? Again thank you Nae.

Comment: Perhaps try `width=self.innerFrame.winfo_reqwidth()` on canvas.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately the canvas shrinks below the frame width, so the frame shows nothing. I can still move the scrollbar.